# Triangular code, triangular output

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, restricted-source, self-referential

For this challenge, submissions should be a program or function shaped like a right triangle, which produces a right triangle of the same size.

**What is a right triangle?**

For this challenge, a right triangle consists of 1 or more lines, each containing a number of characters (assume all non-newline characters are the same width) equal to that line number:

```
.
..
...
....
```

Trailing newlines are allowed.

**The challenge:**

Your code should form a right triangle, and output a right triangle with the same height made up of any non-newline characters.

As this is code golf, shortest answer in bytes per language wins.

Comment: So, to be clear, 1 byte solutions outputting a single character are valid? Also, for longer solutions, must all characters in the output be the same, as in your example? And why are functions disallowed?

Comment: @Shaggy Yes, 1 byte solutions would be valid (though for most golfing languages this is probably trivial anyway), characters do not need to be the same, and I actually think I'll revise the rules to allow functions.

Comment: Based on "made up of any non-newline characters", a null byte is allowed, right?

Comment: @S.S.Anne Yes, I'd say the only bytes not allowed would be `\n` and `\r` (0x0a and 0x0d)

Comment: I recommend making sure the output is at least one character different than the source code. Otherwise it would allow quine program submissions.

Comment: @petStorm A triangular quine is still pretty non-trivial in most languages

Comment: Is trailing whitespace allowed at the end every line of the output?

Comment: @petStorm I think that sort of defeats the purpose of the challenge

Comment: Does “1 or more lines, each containing a number of characters equal to that line number” imply unique characters. I thought it was asking for repetitious characters with repetition = line number.

Comment: @vol7ron No, it just means the length of each line should be the same as the line number. The output can be made up of any character(s).

Comment: May we exit the program with an exception? (Assuming of course that we've outputted the required output)

Comment: @mathjunkie Sure, why not

Comment: I have the feeling this challenge would have been better as a code-bowling challenge tbh :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I thought about it, but it might be difficult to prevent comments/string literals (since requiring programs to be pristine would make right triangles impossible with more verbose languages)

Answer (score 20):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 34 bytes

```r
#
d=
cat
d(9^
(1:7)
,sep="
")#####
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X5krxZYrObGEK0XDMo5Lw9DKXJNLpzi1wFaJS0lTGQT@/wcA)

Outputs \$9^1\$ to \$9^7\$:

```r
9
81
729
6561
59049
531441
4782969
```

Comment: Nice answer! It appears the decimal representation of `9^n` is `n` digits long up to `n=21`.

Answer (score 14):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 53 bytes

*Fixed error pointed out by @S.S. Anne*

```c
\
m\
ain
(n){
9<pr\
intf(\
"%d\n",
n*=9)||\
main(n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z@GKzeGKzEzj0sjT7Oay9KmoCiGKzOvJE0jhktJNSUmT0mHK0/L1lKzpgaoEqgOqMy69v9/AA)

Answer (score 11):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 1 byte

```
.
```

Outputs a single null byte.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9f7/9/AA)

Comment: The fun thing with brainfuck is you can do this with nothing but dots over any number of lines!

Comment: @Hand-E-Food Not quite. You'll need a 10 for the newline, so you can do it with `+`, `<`, `>`, and `.`

Comment: It still won't work without loops, because if you have to print more bytes than you have dots, you will inevitably need to reuse them.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>43</s>  34 bytes

A triangle of 7 rows, filled with `0`'s.

```javascript
f
=(
s=`
`)=>
s[7]?
'':0+s
+f(0+s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/jctWg6vYNoErQdPWjqs42jzWnktd3cpAu5hLO00DSGn@T87PK87PSdXLyU/XSNPQ1PwPAA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f   // f is a recursive function
=(   // taking
s=`   // a string s initialized to
`)=>   // a linefeed
s[7]?   // if s has more than 7 characters,
'':0+s   // stop recursion; otherwise append a 0, followed by s,
+f(0+s)   // followed by the result of a recursive call with 0 + s
```

Comment: [Different method (still 34 bytes), full program](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P4/L1oArLb@IS8NaW5srz8bCWpOroCgzr0SDy1JLK0/T2vr/fwA "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online")

Comment: [19 byte quine](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/jctWg0vT1o5LQSEByE7QVkj7n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaahqfkfAA)? Is this valid?

Comment: @tsh There's apparently [no consensus anymore](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13634/58563) about that kind of quines.

Comment: @Arnauld But this question does not require a proper quine.

Comment: @tsh You're right, I did not remember this challenge accurately. Your solution looks valid indeed. I think you should post it as a new answer.

Answer (score 9):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>66</s> <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 19 bytes

```perl
#
##
use
####
Quine
```

I am submitting this as a joke because I did not even bother trying to write some optimized code.  Instead, I am using a module from CPAN that causes the program to print itself.

The `Quine.pm` module can be found on CPAN and was released in January 2001, long before this question was posted here.  So I assume that it is acceptable, as it seems to be the tradition in other Code Golf questions.

Edit 1: Saved 12 bytes by removing the semicolon after the `use` statement.

Edit 2: Thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) for pointing out that I did not need the final newline character, saving one byte.

Edit 3: Thanks to [petStorm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92069/petstorm) who made a great improvement by putting the `use` statement and the module name on separate lines, reducing the program to only 19 bytes.  This exercise that started as a joke is now a very competitive entry.  It would be difficult to do better in a non-obscure language (insert joke about Perl's readability here).

Comment: So, can [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5tvgThfhVX/) work? I tried it and it didn't throw a syntax error.

Comment: It does work and it produces the expected output without errors.  Thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Answer (score 9):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 26 bytes

The `dc` command turns out to be quite useful in code-golfing.

```bash
\
d\
c \
-e{\
5..1\
0}*p \
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P4YrJYYrWSGGSze1OobLVE/PMIbLoFarQCHm/38A)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>53</s> 43 bytes

I think we are allowed to output different characters. Because of this, I simply printed \$10^i\$ at every iteration.

```python
#
##
###
i=1;
exec\
"prin\
t i;i*\
=10;"*8\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/X5lLGYSUuTJtDa25UitSk2O4lAqKMvNiuEoUMq0ztWK4bA0NrJW0LGL@/wcA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>76</s> <s>64</s> 53 bytes

```hs
u
 =
 (9
 ^) 
 <$>[
 1..9]
main=  
 mapM_  
 print u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v5RLwZZLQcOSSyFOU4FLwUbFLppLwVBPzzKWKzcxM89WASiYm1jgGw9iFBRl5pUolCr8/w8A)

This prints the first 9 powers of 9.

Comment: 43 bytes with the help of explicit layout: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v5qr1JYrN7GAS8MyTpMr2lBPz4Ir1jo3MTOPy1ZBASjhy1VQlJlXolBa@/8/AA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```ruby
(
##
1..
7)##
.map{
|x|p(#
9**x)}#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X4NLWZnLUE@Py1wTyNDLTSyo5qqpqCnQUOay1NKq0KxV/v8fAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>64</s> <s>53</s> 43 bytes

```cs
;
;;
int
s=1,
i;for
(;i++<
9;Print
(s*=9));
```

Simply prints the first several powers of 9.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P/fmsvamiszr4Sr2NZQhyvTOi2/iEvDOlNb24bL0jqgCCSjUaxla6mpaf3/PwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 34 bytes

Outputs \$ 9^k, 1 \leq k \leq 7 \$.

```
v
8v
<v1
v< @
> 9*v
.^ >\:
a,:|>1-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/v4zLoozLpsyQq8xGwYHLTsFSq4xLL07BLsaKK1HHqsbOUPf/fwA)

The first three lines

```
v
8v
<v1
```

push 8 (loop counter) and 1 (\$ 9^0 \$). The main loop can be written in a single line as

```
9*\1-a,:!#@_\:.
9*               multiply by 9
  \              swap to loop counter
   1-            subtract 1
     a,          output newline
       :!        duplicate and invert loop counter
         #@_     quit if non-zero, continue east otherwise
            \    swap to 9^k
             :.  duplicate and output 9^k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/38KwjKvMxobLzlIrxlA3UcdKUdkhPsZK7/9/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 1 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4P9/AA)

Not much to say I guess..

---

If this was [code-bowling](/questions/tagged/code-bowling) instead, we could do something like this (can be made as arbitrary large as you'd want it to, as long as the last three bytes are `₄*»`):

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111
1111111
11111111
111111111
1111111₄*»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fkMsQhMAYQkBJGAWnEQw461FTi9ah3f//AwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
1\n11\n111\n...  # Push all these numbers one by one to the stack
111...111        # Push the number of the last line
₄*               # Multiply it by 1000 to increase its size by 3
»                # Join everything on the stack by newlines
                 # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 53 bytes

```c
;
m\
ain
(n){
9/pr\
intf(\
"%d\n",
n)&&mai\
n(n*10);}
```

Prints powers of 10.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/9@aKzeGKzEzj0sjT7Oay1K/oCiGKzOvJE0jhktJNSUmT0mHK09TTS03MTOGK08jT8vQQNO69v9/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 43 bytes

```php
;
1;
for
(;$i
++<8;
)echo(
10**$i-
1)."\n";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkrbkMrbnS8ou4NKxVMrm0tW0srLk0U5Mz8jW4DA20tFQydbkMNfWUYvKUrP//BwA)

Not that bad for PHP.. displays a triangle of "9"

Answer (score 4):

## Java 10, 76 bytes (11 rows)

```
v
->
{//
 var
r="";
long i
=0,s=1;
for(;++i
<12;r+=(s
*=9)+"\n")
;return r;}
```

Inspired by all the other answers.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7NCsIwEITv@xRLT4m19ecmMb6BXgQv6iHGVqIxLZs0INJnryn2sjA7zMz3VFEVz/tr0FZ5j3tl3BcQjQsV1UpXeBgl4jGQcQ/U7NSYO0Yu0reHdHxQwWg8oEM5RCh28F0sAKMiIJllAmyTcgbkcu7lSkDdEBN5bmC7WgvKJfMwkxueZxeXcRBUhY4ckugHMda33c2m@mkljuPvxMj@POcrKj4Bfnyo3mXThbJNVmCu1Mx11vKJtR9@)

Comment: I wonder why Java doesn't support backslash line continuers.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I'm actually wondering why other languages do support backslash line continues. What's the purpose of it in regular programming, apart from benig able to split long strings to multiple lines without using `"\n+"`?

Comment: C has macros that can't take up multiple lines without them. If you want to have a big macro, it won't be readable unless you use the backslash like continuation. The same applies to line-based languages, too. I guess Java is neither of those, so it doesn't need them.

Answer (score 4):

## [SQL (Oracle)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) <strike>88</strike> 76 Bytes

```sql
;
/*
ABC
DEFG
HIJ*/
SELECT
LPAD(1,
LEVEL,1)
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY
LEVEL < 12;
```

[Try it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b181b/7/0)

Output:

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111
1111111
11111111
111111111
1111111111
11111111111
```

Edit: Thanks [@Math Junkie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65425/math-junkie), by following the rules I actually cut off 12 bytes.

Comment: This is an interesting post, but unfortunately, it misses the point of the challenge. The triangle formed by the source code should be increasing in size, the same way as the output

Comment: @mathjunkie I read the question like 3 times, it doesn't state that it needs to be increasing size, just that the code form a right triangle.  It also doesn't specify that the output be the same direction as the code, only that it be the same height.  The code and output triangles are the same (Just reflected across the X-axis)

Comment: In the section of the description describing a right triangle, it mentions that the number of characters on a line should be "equal to that line number"

Comment: @mathjunkie You are definitely correct, I missed that.  Shoot and I thought I found a loophole.

Comment: @mathjunkie Actually thank you for pointing out my error. When I reformatted, I was actually able to save 1 line and therefore 12 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## SmileBASIC 4, 3 bytes

```
\
?0
```

---

```
0
OK
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 43 bytes

```
\
"\
"<\
>".\
"~Ta\
ble~#\
&/@Ran\
ge [8*1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P4ZLCYhsYrjslPSAjLqQxBiupJzUOuUYLjV9h6DEvBiu9FSFaAstw9j/AUWZeSUK@g7p//8DAA)

Comment: I like the backslash making the triangle smoother

Answer (score 3):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <s>103</s> <s>89</s> 76 bytes

```clj
(
;;
;;;
loop
[i 9]
(when(
* i;;;;
99999999
)(println
i)(recur(*
i 9))));;;;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtBCsAgDATv@wqP0R9InlJ6EqEpEiVU@vxUocPeZqe0fk@r7gTmNUbrfeCQkE/Qe1UlpCC8Tf5BpGGiT1NIJKtlGiWsIi720/0D)

Prints the first 11 powers of 9. Exits with an `ArithmeticException: integer overflow` when trying to multiply \$9^{12}\$ by \$99999999\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 1 [byte](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

Boring solution, just like everyone else. :)

```
\
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTVD,v=8)

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

Non-trivial attempt.

```
＼
２＼
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNDJTBBJXVGRjEyJXVGRjND,v=8)

## Explanation

```
＼    # Draw a diagonal, with nothing on the stack
      # Errors silently
      # Newline: A character not in the code page.
      # It basically does nothing.
２    # 2: Push 2 onto the stack
  ＼  # Draw a diagonal with a length of 2
      # Implicit output
```

Comment: I think the new-line might be equivalent to the pilcrow at byte 10 of the code-page, `¶`, [try it](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNDJUI2JXVGRjEyJXVGRjND)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 43 bytes

```bash
\
s\
eq\
 -f\
'seq\
 -s "\
" %f' \
$[+8]|sh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P4arOIYrtTCGS0E3LYZLvRjCLFZQiuFSUlBNU1eI4VKJ1raIrQEpBgA)

I couldn't quite get this down to 7 rows; I needed to pad it by 4 bytes to fill out the 8-row triangle (that's why I have `$[+8]` in the code instead of just `8`).

---

**BSD Challenge!**

If you take the same idea as the GNU solution above but use the BSD utility `jot` instead of `seq`, it's just one byte too long for a 7-row solution (which would be 34 bytes):

```bash
    \
    j\
    ot\
     -w\
    'jot\
     -s "\
    " ' 7|sh
# This is one byte too long for 7 rows :( .
```

**If someone can see how to shave just 1 byte** off this BSD version, that would get it down to a 7-row 34-byte solution.

Here's a [TIO link to the BSD version](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P4YrK4YrvySGS0G3PIZLPQvCLFZQiuFSUlBXMK8BKQIA) if anybody wants to try their hand at eliminating that one last byte!  This also works under OS X, if you have a Macintosh.

(Obviously this version, like the GNU version in my main answer above, can be padded to be another 8-row 43-byte solution, but that's not as interesting.)

Comment: I have a [26-byte solution](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P4YrJYYrWSGGSze1OobLVE/PMIbLoFarQCHm/38A) if you want.

Comment: @dingledooper  That's a nice one. It's completely different from mine; go ahead and post it yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I'll do.

Comment: I love the smooth edge on your triangle!

Comment: @Hand-E-Food Thank you\

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 64 bytes

```bash
\
d\
at\
e +\
d%n%\
m%n%j\
%n%Y%n\
%R%n%:z\
%n%7Y%n%\
T%n%N%n%F\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P4YrJYYrsSSGK1VBG8hWzVON4coFklkxXEAyUjUPSAcBWVZVYAHzSLCKECDpB8RuMf//AwA)

Not the shortest but kind of fancy. Displays current date in convinient format. Tried to do it locales intependent. Last byte for fancy too.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 53 bytes

```c
\
m\
ain
(n){
for(;
9/n;n=
printf(
"%0*d\n"
,n,0));;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z@GKzeGKzEzj0sjT7OaKy2/SMOay1I/zzrPlqugKDOvJE2DS0nVQCslJk@JSydPx0BT09q69v9/AA)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 53 bytes

```c
\
m\
ain
(n){
9/n&&
main(\
printf(
"%0*d\n"
,n,0));;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z@GKzeGKzEzj0sjT7Oay1I/T02NKxfI14jhKijKzCtJ0@BSUjXQSonJU@LSydMx0NS0tq79/x8A)

Answer (score 3):

## C Preprocessor, 65 bytes (10 lines)

```
.
..
...
....
.....
......
.......
........
.........
__TIME__//
```

Process with GCC/Clang with `-E` and `-P` options. (Thanks to Calculuswhiz for suggesting the `-P` option.)

All the dots are ignored. The predefined `__TIME__` macro expands to a string of the form `"HH:MM:SS"`, meaning the last line stays the same length.

Comment: Try the `-P` option too.

Comment: And just a style thing, but instead of ending with two spaces, how about `//`?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Thanks for the tip. I didn't know about the `-P` option. And you're right: the slashes are cleared than the spaces. I made both of the changes you suggested.

Comment: No problem! I saw your answer, and I thought that surely there must a way to remove that stuff! After some Google attempts, I finally found an SO answer on it. Incidentally, those extra garbage lines are called "linemarkers".

Comment: Although... maybe you want to mention the 1-byte `.` solution.

Comment: I figured that one was obvious :P I was trying to do something a little more imaginative. Originally, I was browsing the list of standard macros and thought that `__TIME__` expanded to 8 characters--the same number of characters in `__TIME__` itself--, which would have been perfect, but I forgot to account for the quotes :( This solution was a hack on the original idea.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
₁
¶₂
ΘI₃
↑3İ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr///igoEKwrbigoIKzphJ4oKDCuKGkTPEsOKBsP//)

No comment characters, so every element does something...

```
₁       # run function on line 1 (next line)
¶₂      # split output of function on line 2 (next line)
ΘI₃     # prepend zero to identity of function on line 3 (next line)
↑3İ⁰    # first 3 elements of powers of 10
```

---

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 1 byte

*Trivial (but included for completeness)*

```
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/D/fwA)

(there are many more like this... all equally uninteresting...)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 4 bytes

Trivial power (up to 19 lines)

```powershell
1
10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f/fkMvQ4P9/AA)

---

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 4 bytes

p–n junction (90 variants)

```powershell
1
-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f/fkEvX8P9/AA)

---

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 26 bytes

Twinkle, twinkle, little star

```powershell
,
'*
*'*
6|%{
'*' *
++$ko}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fh0tdi0sLiM1qVKuBbHUFLS5tbZXs/Nr//wE)

---

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 26 bytes

The magic number in nuclear physics and the quark soup of 3 quarks `$_`

```powershell
,
1+
2..
6|%{
"$_"*
$_};$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fh8tQm8tIT4/LrEa1mktJJV5Ji0slvtZaJf7/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## TeX, 188 bytes

Nothing out of the ordinary, but for completeness:

```
%
%%
%%%
%%%%
%%%%%
%%%%%%
%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%
\countdef
~=1%%%%%%%
\countdef%%
\i=26\loop%%
\advance~1{%%
\loop\advance%
\i1.\ifnum\i<~%
\repeat\endgraf}
\ifnum~<18\repeat
\bye%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>34</s> 26 bytes (<s>7</s> 6 lines)

*-8 bytes / 1 line* thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)!

```
 
10
  6
iota
  n^v
stack.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeWChIqVigoSi0pqSwoyswrUShOLSxNzUtOLVaw/q/AZWjApaBgxpWZX5IIZOTFlXEVlyQmZ@v9/w8A)

**Output:**

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
100000
```

Comment: I was able to reduce by one line using `n^v` ([TIO](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeWChIqVigoSi0pqSwoyswrUShOLSxNzUtOLVaw/q/AZWjAZaagwJWZX5LIlRdXBmQWlyQmZ@v9/w8A)). Using `stack.` is a nice idea.

Comment: Wow, thank you @Bubbler !

Answer (score 3):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 103 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 103 bytes

Filename as follows (if your filesystem doesn't support LF, I'm sorry) (also requires to be ASCII-compatible):

```
x
.p
x.n
.o.n
.o04x
.-.t.z
.c.zxxx
.a.m.m.w
.sx.oab.-
.s.-.c.a.s
.c.o.c.$.mx
.s.s.+.tao.-
.s.m.a.dxxxxx
```

Content is empty.

[Try it online, with rpxem!](https://tio.run/##5VhLc9s2EL7zV8BxHEmxDCedTA@qFLsPt3WnaTpOcspkOBAJSohJggVAS3Li354uCJAAH3acTHOqPabJfXy7WAC7C4hyufu0j1K2PBbFlmbHUpHoEotlkPG4TCm6@BuoAUJRSqRErzQXzdGPQpAdUBGKaYJYzhQjKbum48dErOQUPVqmPLqcVBIIybKg4hYWy4qUhtGaRpfjx5KmieHQPA4a/KKU6/uoa4nP2mwhl7lcs0R9G/D5/Nvgvn23@DZxZrmkQn0b7IwUe/81ciHYFVG0sXF7YPU7piRao5ijj/D10TIQYgka7wEFMxmSE3SeK7qiYtLwERKESQpLflVmNFdnQnCBc7pBo5qEslIqtKS18qhR1o6238x//awG4W89BtqiEBSeegMK@k/JBEUjGZE8GQXDO/LcKVX4RCkRkiiiUnKBZhD2guUrxxKUxFTA16za6VM0UzQrgqG9bHUXH27qaJxaElpoWVKmKrSU8QRnVKwapc4K2EcvC5ojkseIbmlUKooI0uNACUvdBHIQGmvKFFXeLaqxzmZV2tExnyLt7SJnae2SKPPxr6CBl0TSnGS00p9MUUVsACdYD9zCGpSei2dtzyIeO8@0GY2jLQAKL0VEF6PR/f08ddqnRl2/GG9OtTDEtBapVmq43CmKFQ9Jba/lvYVdlklCBUBEpYAJnyJAWKk1gPVdejJ1XmAjF1iYzRroaGxRIMEbttsF0ZoIAG3031rRd43EPvrl7Kc3v6Hfzy7OGuKr17@cXVzgolQSPdj/YJVuZmj/g0a8mdoXHK3FzYNGrfbjcIGetjZq10H06BF69j1aLIyD8KWd047adfi277G2hWO@ySNYMe/8je57q1VuYZmY4/ec5eMH0wc@gplRbAqWkfPZhjIwOZ5MGMI6jsNwrD1oYQ8FhaaS9gzguqzpoExuSUb1/qGqFLl1vJ@2O9vcKn3wZv38@GXzNSpGaPEcjXipIFIhSdPR1DG5z/QZeUsrLzOfyQyT5R2l0KNbHc@rV81wKuHICEe82PkY0pDVWvBNSDakxbwyTEGvqJC0Da@TCyQIyL25kk4lqVVIHOp158NRw6NZKaBmteEuSDM1ICksChDbYn9yXjixjRHb@Ea2hrb1aTtDa43t2tCufRoxNNK2@RpyDRdE7KCGUuKklQ0dD3U28nEyw0kEz2qenyQ4yrlau7UEGrHRuOKsM@AXBFJUI3ZoHYxjKFE8920eGZYsl0qQqMvdM9wMFjIrUhaRrsBDI/BPyRWDGfVZBzWyKNJSNpyboT7E1hFczFxFa3ZCK9Ma8g@trqDW5l1tqwlvUZNgeAG9awpFvqZAoNXupAeW91yBrVIDCug4PMSeMpt5bYFzRKqY5ZDEICee/4VXVEVBP/sZoRMjjLmI0QwdPe3VXBx2bHj@tZJp1QSNRwfxaNIHiRyI3uID@vYdWibVV5dO3aWCDshAeK6cmk0SbR1L3OspJr6iTRVDY7aNQqcdqHH746AO16aZIdQo5TnFuqHxGpFWR4IrkYE4C89xl7J89HHVzaPHXtwm2mvWB9s4sLr@vS@hD6oa8taq1nX9iS7yHmgPbuvgtl2479C8UZbQ2mpAbyc9vxt555B3X4g8vxv52iFffyHy3dH4Q6MkXGwIbDzFYVcIQWXB81gfVzBpzGpz1nLES@C55sL2hBUZ5zy/poKfTD7fo5l@rN93@b2MlnurS5cuVbo0QSl6h1kepWVMT/rKh0/bbZuPVXvecqTqjLSVqqwtvg7xqIPoFen@wW4gIv5UEzfVpCMPZr7rzMHRPSfhfxjvVtyeDpyu64grL6ubLqWOuz1u3ZHaM6fb9DFDVaU6R@ronjYSPkzsYHRz0@MfeovCdjW31y696w/9Ta/tdrNEz8TRDLn7EdceDaVuz85RK3@TpbyfsT03nnazdfeoHn/xqB46Q3XTNjSiZOEBPx9L//MEJccSmhJ5nNzP5sHMC2TVDX6FyYPK5MFnTA5fEN16KzufI3031rgHB8oxL3TcpXd5Y8@c3oUR9gTvvFjLqFrzOMyYlPqux1xjDN7Y2eOk6QJshwpWsK0@oeInrYOt5rVOvIO4rSPpXVA9Hvr40V4wOtFOhINP@@j36lZshtZKFXJ2fLxial0uccSz482lujTxh7lYlgoxBJPAEkZjxBQiaAlPKLXg27JcrfTBpsaDqYtoLkGwzPXni/PXNSn49a8fX5wt5vMR@MAT7dzeKNgGuAi2OA8wrx5PngHlCCt8HeAIX2@38ElwBr@bAMst5mSJj@ANZCJgSC3F4e8hzraaLPEhVoQbmQwk4q3@CZzN4NXLNxc/ny1Go0/V@qj6wsq3KTKsyad/AQ)

### Output

```
x
10
120
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

### With comments

Note that every LF is replaced with '?'.

```
x?.pXX.z # print'x', LF
.a?x.nXX.z # print LF.ord # two-digits
.a?.oXX.z # print LF
.a.n?.sXX.z
.a04x?.-.tXX.z # i = 4
.a.zXX.z # loop
  .a?.c.zxxx?.aXX.z # essentially nop
  .a.m.m.wXX.z # j = i; while j!=0
    .a?.sx.oXX.z # print'x'
    .aab.-?.s.-.cXX.z # j--
  .a.a.s?.c.oXX.z # end-while; print LF
  .a.c.$.mx?.s.s.+.tXX.z # i++
  .aao.-?.s.mXX.z # break if !(14>i)
.a.a.dxxxxx # end-loop; end program
```

Comment: I will admit, when I saw your username I expected INTERCAL

Answer (score 3):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 26 bytes

```
;
=a
0W>
6aO*
'.'=a
+1aQQQ
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##lVhbc9M4FH7vr3C9bGPFrpsyDDvEdTvQLTvMQgq0wOwmgciykhgcO/jSFhLvX2fPkW9yboWXTix9Ojd956J@pjc0ZpE3Tw6D0OU/mE/jWPk78CbT5CKKwkjhdwkP3FgRX4ssB7ymUcyb@9KZEvU2DRJvdj/uKok4nS1YGMRJlLIkjDRKFsnUi804TCPGbZrBjjf/MPUSHs8p41qxP6MJm2pHH7X@YDjoD2JYz7pDfflb/@MgGLa1QbB8QEj7iGRzzr/AbsSTNAoUSXi/M1wug9T3s1yYYzC7QxY@TxRqOya/40yT4MQqROAR27bpGf7oyhBb@m3GqQO2axTUmD4PJsmUGLTPhiRLQnDcCyYbrcoyEQ7l@p/XF1d2f2jloXpP/ZQv4oQmHlPmeAuaQxaOuRYeawxRvKER@NCx6IkQU@i3qK7n/jFbrPfp0CxlWd5YY6Swh2WSr1mUBiLsUXirBPw2Z0TmciedbFjf4p0QYtabgOulM4dHW3DlJuCehaHPabAFWO1mBateQjAi6lfEy0O3QrI4naN0Q4j65NKEAtdyRyUlG5wpvutzmzwpvpugNTfKBRnGv/poXoGgigdW04DxcJx7LblxcCAZD3zMf5VRQOFVCIqQrPGn5HqdTdfPh6T/9PDfYfvIOK4oTw8O8IJRpqZeq6iNZG46m1fOjEpnHoj8zMgo85Np7cp@bevBAW1c20TGKTJuvwnMcjLP03iq4Sqx8lS56L1/8fay9@qid20vsiJhXrg8SFY4cJ/7fXr4/dMQ/3YOn3yCEKwGQAgFY7NdbPIQBGxqxkcc9cYe4PIQ5TgMFJjrTQKUI3nSrzHDipq5wVtQmME3oecqnX28n9Jyq05QuS5ro3fBlyC8DRSvskxpNUxrjZoxFy6QMr5SdH@WXgNXXw8pBLRIF0pWSVVs1JyiritxpTxfc0anUukgGdTgnfDDJnyW@jvh7Sbc9W5kL@stvInGJZSiXtFkagJvAiZJPQK/t12Sek6DIEwUUAV3ojjflO88ClUwNXR/UXet8Hd6rz4Qn/qhpG8e3u7WV4tfLvc1etIhP@V8u/0T3vO7eRggSWnChUFKEkJtDPgE@HbDFTCOR2Ckv6WSnMj3trXenDZQDeLXtO9BQ9zNe6l6V8TvFSWV5JxHIY0SUlYQbLcrOaAiWCPqrs4g5BXO3xNKFs7ATC6OmGoVjF88JQcH18roQHO8NzhIIcemUs9RW0MCc1w8uBq2z8jg@Mh4KGiF0QBmOTKRQAMOK/kQQ818uEOw2sK2xJbLltrCH6R2qR5aseiBVTMvACa5ytc0BELxgIUpLnO3qzxY0Gy0qaUL@5t5ZBx3yHLZWalZxYCwq2ahE6MCUChcLz0IqnWZEZ9zCr1HrkD3ML4atXYyvkLJlwqLRXeFU9S9@hawLs3siH9NvYhr6jhWibHAEVlsOdIWm3q@@2kehYzHiHr@rnd@/eKyd1X35udQA3a1Zokl@QXDZF6J6TtSpxM3Lc2qlsSrs67IOn1pkqOcMRznaZyP8cOF@dg9YeVs7Jaz8dgWFpmlKahsf7yFTq886N3BRKHRJJ3hwPFg4erHmQJKlDF6CR3VwUZq8TywY5JJd4yB0JjhGHxlpIAltjJWoDib5r8DOuO2k/8G1bHN1mdXcUAzTbNCVZUlr@Iqak@8MNBUvZJahcdRypFTHKW6rRqKqjtmLqPq4rq6Vpsunc@cJaYXC/4aMC5l40KVEvGJFydcuEgWENpj7FXlA2nlLaGpPTBJmaUw5DmQqHeUJf43BXqBwqY0gi@YWfwwmEBNsmqC0KHtSBohMFXnkq@2SDJ4gWqOlAdErj31GJW/N6yNNFB7oXKDkqFQpr6LtgoV7j7USimrMODEqEKgvlYNjdinxZNMVQ3HfpaOxzwyqe@HTIMB3A0xSFTrACM6MJEbQHkHnpTEAcO/WEwHV28h47h2DF1Y7IiXnIm59cGDxFcHgUoIs5kZ@x68EDuGclhP9mWlYSSTLXubW9Zo3WM/BF8fPXzy6MnjPx4@edwWqxEN3HCGYZPPX6gGtU8xZLQR2hrSetpCSJXoeXgLqxy5u4EBZ6WZuSRzHIWzc2DAeejCoFm8nUi3NFe@TpMVuKcJzmyykc@EkVReOs@Xisel@Ctvj8R21Yeazm1xVH0jDhUF0eR33moVl7D7lQLx1mo@gBrIlxUSPZYNKZNJRv@J3DqtxrdGsEvL4sQN08S8jaBxg8A8z4lBGzG7bAqqtRbS1MFAPA/Lf38A1c62KCgQHaNMf8CS7kbwCLvk3ogY1fQk26QDWbGc1BeHLbfwshGGwzUkvhA2IdtrSOzQm5BHa0jxLtiA/H1dZrjZzo9rSDF/b0CeVMiKNOURnA2qI/KZ0@1nJtvOnG0/g8V/45mD6oxGywxv/MfmrDjWbeTg8t5jtOus56YlHct3jU0BsyVYo8rg43a5BJXSQ7@Z0tQsXuqOXel3GsI/VMIX2EetRvpaZCXxNpL5RS4C2r99SjcGi637/pd0SASttttwGs81AxuB9FnWsiodUchyqarNqF0VClyhojx0jyrXdtc1V@Ay63HAP6M6zJd1RXCIzvTaJN3Frly3jv9acu1rPuIBB9EZ/bD2bLrX@XC695hetvdaZgs@9WP65s2bHyN4hXrYsqwf/wM)

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 4 bytes

```
B
1f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9@JyzDt/38A)

**Explanation:**

```
B   Push 11 on the stack.
1   Push 1 on the stack.
f   Print the items on the stack, starting at the top, each one with a terminal newline.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 43 bytes

A lot more "content" than my previous submissions.

```
\
 \
  \
for(
i,1,8
,(9**i
)     \
println)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//z@GSwGIgDgtv0iDK1PHUMeCS0fDUksrk0tTAQRiuAqKMvNKcvI0//8HAA)

Comment: Readability improvement: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//z@GSwGIgDgtvyiGSyNTxzCGS8dCR8MyhktLK1MTJFNQlJlXkpOn@f8/AA "Io – Try It Online")

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Nice modification. However, I'm not going to accept it, because in my opinion, a one-liner in a case like this is much more readable than a line-breaked program.

Answer (score 2):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 76 bytes

```erlang
f
()
->[
%%%%
%%%%%
string
:copies
("!", X)
++"\n"||X
<- lists :
seq(1,11)].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcTBCoMwDADQe76iKwgJWqHXMvwOwXkQSSXgqmsKXvz3buwdHud9SZtjXbOcpUKNgARumKD5@deAlixpg7Aep7AC2oftzEjQtvaV7H2P8HRmFy1qAih/0Hfe09zX9yIJp5mMG4wcIV5ZCmNEor5@AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
#
##
###
for\
i in\
range(
9):####
 print(#
10**i)###
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X5lLGYSUudLyi2K4MhUy82K4ihLz0lM1uCw1rZRBMgoFRZl5JRrKXIYGWlqZmkCh//8B) Similar to dingledooper's submission. I was also going to submit:

### [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 1 byte!!

```python
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9f7/9/AA) But S.S.Anne beat me by a couple of hours :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/g/38A)

---

The vast majority of atoms can be used for this, printing `0` or `1`.  The few exceptions are listed as follows: (incomplete, didn't check past `Ẓ` in the [Atoms](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Atoms) page)

- `³⁴⁵⁹`: prints more than one digit
- `½°`: prints `0.0`
- `~`: prints `-1`
- `⁷`: prints `\n`
- `⁸IRḶṬẈ`: prints nothing
- `MTZ`: errors
- `Ɠƈɠ`: interacts with STDIN

Borderline:

- <s>`Ọ`: prints null character</s> (allowed per [S.S. Anne's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203062/triangular-code-triangular-output/203099#comment482001_203099))

Comment: The null character is fine. See my brainfuck answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [HQ9+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9+), 1 byte

```
Q
```

[Try it online!](https://almnet.de/esolang/hq9plus.php)

Answer (score 2):

## [dirt](https://github.com/0xB0C5/dirt), 43 bytes

```
x
xx
xx|
|'a'
(a*'a
)**{1|
}.*|"11
11111"|x
```

run with with empty string as input:

```
>dirt triangle.dirt -i ""
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
2
mR
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=2%0AmR&i=&a=1)

Nontrivial solution. Prints "\x01\n\x01\x02", so you won't see any output, but it's there. One byte is easy but boring.

```
2     Push 2
mR    For n in [1,2], print [1..n] as a string
```

Another 4-byter that feels like cheating:

```
0     Do nothing
|?    Source of program, implicit print.
```

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code (32-bit), 43 bytes

As symbols in codepage 437:

```
`
!Q
!j
!Y_j
Q░x≤¬
'YX¬A╢
Ç∙ëq∞Çε
ê7af║█¡├
```

Hexdump:

```
600a
21510a
216a010a
21595f6a0a
51b078f3aa0a
275958aa41b60a
80f98971ec80ee0a
88376166badbadc3
```

A `fastcall` function which receives the pointer to output buffer in `ecx`. It fills the buffer with a triangle containing the letter `x`:

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
```

Disassembly:

```
10013FF0 60                   pushad  
10013FF1 0A 21                or          ah,byte ptr [ecx]  
10013FF3 51                   push        ecx  
10013FF4 0A 21                or          ah,byte ptr [ecx]  
10013FF6 6A 01                push        1  
10013FF8 0A 21                or          ah,byte ptr [ecx]  
10013FFA 59                   pop         ecx  
10013FFB 5F                   pop         edi  
10013FFC 6A 0A                push        0Ah  
10013FFE 51                   push        ecx  
10013FFF B0 78                mov         al,78h  
10014001 F3 AA                rep stos    byte ptr es:[edi]  
10014003 0A 27                or          ah,byte ptr [edi]  
10014005 59                   pop         ecx  
10014006 58                   pop         eax  
10014007 AA                   stos        byte ptr es:[edi]  
10014008 41                   inc         ecx  
10014009 B6 0A                mov         dh,0Ah  
1001400B 80 F9 89             cmp         cl,89h  
1001400E 71 EC                jno         again (10013FFCh)  
10014010 80 EE 0A             sub         dh,0Ah  
10014013 88 37                mov         byte ptr [edi],dh  
10014015 61                   popad  
10014016 66 BA DB AD          mov         dx,0ADDBh  
1001401A C3                   ret
```

I used various instructions to insert a new-line byte `0A` into the machine code:

```
10013FF1 0A 21                or          ah,byte ptr [ecx]  
10014009 B6 0A                mov         dh,0Ah  
10014010 80 EE 0A             sub         dh,0Ah
```

At the end of the program, I needed to pad it with 4 bytes. I used a harmless `MOV` command instead of 4 `NOP`s so I could have hexadecimal `BADBAD` in code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 53 bytes

A triangular quine.

```perl
$
_=
q{$
_='$
_='."
q{$_}"
.";eva"
.l;print
###};eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@FK96Wq7AaRKmDCT0lEDe@VolLT8k6tSwRSOdYFxRl5pVwKSsr14KEcv7/BwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

Any one of `0123456789@NQXY_adg‹›¾ÊËåð` will work. They will output one of `0123456789101120000000011`  respectively.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>103</s> <s>53</s> 34 bytes

```powershell
#
##
$n`
=1;`
$n..`
7|%{(`
$n*=9)}
```

A Powershell port of the R solution by *Robin Ryder*, thanks!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fmUtZmUslL4HL1tA6AcjQ00vgMq9RrdYAcbRsLTVr//8HAA)

[Previous attempt 2](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fmUtJi0tLKwGIIQSUhFFwGshQ0VDSUtKy0FT6/x8A)

[Previous attempt 1](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f9fmUtJi0tLKwGIIQSUhFFwGsFAYiEzUdhaSkBzlbQMjazBlPH//wA)

Answer (score 2):

## BRASCA, 1 byte

Yep, it's another one of these.

Pick any one of these:

```
0123456789oOnNlLeEdDhHK+-*^s}r&|_ABmM?!ST<>=Y
```

### Explanation

**TL;DR:** Most instructions work because an empty stack consists of infinite zeroes.

```
0-9       - Pushes the digit, implicit output.
oOnN      - Prints the top/bottom of the stack, which is 0x00 because the stack is empty.
lLeEdDhHK - Pushes 10, 13, 26, 32, 48, 65, 97, 100 and 1000 respectively, implicit output.
+-*^s}    - Operate on zeroes because of an empty stack. (ex. + on an empty stack is 0+0).
r         - Pushes a range between 0 and 0, which is just a single 0.
&|_       - Bitwise operators on zeroes because, once again, of an empty stack.
AB        - Registers are 0 by default.
mM        - Shifting an empty stack pushes a 0.
?         - Pushes a random number between 0 and 0.
!         - Pushes the stack length, which is 0.
S         - Concatenates 0 with 0, creating 0.
T         - Sets implicit output to only output the top of the stack, which is empty, so it's a 0.
<>=Y      - Compares 0 with 0 in a bunch of ways.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
Ｆ
Ｅ⁺
.¦.
×⊕λ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9jaGFyY29hbP//77ymCu@8peKBugouwqYuCsOX4oqVzrsu//8) Explanation: In Charcoal, newlines, which I will represent below with ¶, are simply parts of string literals.

```
Ｆ¶
```

Loop over the characters in the string literal `¶`.

```
Ｅ⁺¶.¦.¶
```

Concatenate the string literals `¶.` and `.¶`, loop over the characters, and print each result on its own line.

```
×⊕λ.
```

Repeat `.` by one more than the character index (0-indexed).

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 1 byte

```
t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//@/5P9/AA)

Sorry, it's a simple literal answer. But then again, all answers in Keg are going to be simple literal answers. Works because characters auto-push and auto-print.

[Here's a script that will generate a triangular source code for any given `n`.](https://tio.run/##y05N///fUE3j0P4aDTUrtZoSTS41Q201zf//LQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 53 bytes

```
;
t:
"*"
loop
( 9)[
print(
(( t)))
insert((
t))1 + 7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@9@aq8SKS0lLiSsnP7@AS0PBUjOaq6AoM69Eg0tDQ6FEU1OTKzOvOLWoREODC8gzVNBWMI/9/x8A)

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>76</s> 64 bytes

```
;
s:
{t:
 "*"
 loop
(10)[p
rint(t)
insert(t
)"*"]}do
trim/all s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@9@aq9iKq7rEiktBSUuJSyEnP7@AS8PQQDO6gKsoM69Eo0STKzOvOLUIyOLSBCqJrU3J5yopyszVT8zJUSjm@v8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>64</s> 53 bytes

```python
#
##
###
for\
i in\
range\
(1, 9):
 print(\
'.' *i )#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X5lLGYSUudLyi2K4MhUy82K4ihLz0lNjuDQMdRQsNa24FAqKMvNKNGK41PXUFbQyFTSV//8HAA)

Removed a line by pushing two lines into one last one, saved 11 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 34 bytes

```sh
:
r\
ep\
eat\
 7 {:
s+=A;:
<<<$s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fiqsohiu1AIgTS2K4FMwVqq24irVtHa2tuGxsbFSKrWv//wcA)

After re-joining lines:

```sh
:           # ':' is a no-op, just to fill space more visibly than ' '
repeat 7 {
    :
    s+=A
    :
    <<< $s
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 1 byte

```
0
```

[Try it online ->](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/3@D/fwA)
Very similar to other answers, shocked that no one posted this before.

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP 0.1](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 1 byte

```
:
```

Outputs top of stack, which is predefined as 1

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, 134

15 lines

```
=
T(
(--
CODE
("owo
(^_^;)
orz")))
&RIGHT(,
)&LEFT(,)
&MID(,1,)&
IF(LN(2),)&
ARRAYFORMULA
(JOIN(CHAR(10
),,REPT(0,ROW(
OFFSET(A1,,,15)
```

#### How It Works

Stall until we have a long enough line for `ARRAYFORMULA`, then catch up by generating 15 rows of an increasing number of 0's using `REPT()` and `ROW(OFFSET())` and joining them together with `JOIN()`. Google Sheets will auto-close the missing parens.

#### Notes

- Hey, look! No duplicate literals, no duplicate function calls, and no spaces. I could have strung together a bunch of `""&`s, but that would be less entertaining.
- The bottleneck here is `ArrayFormula`, so unless there's a way around that, I think we're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel Online, 53

9 lines

```
=
T(
12*
34)&
REPT(
0,ROW(
OFFSET(
A1,,,9))
)&TEXT(,)
```

#### How It Works

Kind of like my [Google Sheets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207514/91403) answer, but the bottleneck is the `REPT()` instead.

Sadly, I cannot break the function name from the open paren. Also, Excel Online does not auto-close, so we're stuck with an extra line. However, some nice things that did help were that Excel Online detects Array Formulas automatically, and it displays Array elements as separate rows, so I get a free line break.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 208 bytes

```java
;
/*
who
they
are*/
public
class//
Main{//h
public //
static//14
void main//
(String[]ar)
{for(int i=0;
i<19;i++){for(
int j=0;j<i+1;j
++)  System.out.
//crucial comment
print('*');System.
out.println();}}}//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczLDoIwEIXh/TxFd9yiI4kbU3wEVy6Ni1qrTIWWlEFDCM@O1bD9zp9j1VttfGecvb@WRQLm8Kk9cG1GUMHkCN1wa0iDblTfI8JJkZsQ69VFpJ4Vk0Ys9/D2dBdtTCKnZw7knperChlMDx9ScizouJNAVXmQVBTZn@HnNrqtqCilhTgIcR57Nu3WD7wFRB0GTaoR2retcQxdvOY0yZNMriH8yj83Ls3kPM@Iy/IF)

A triangular full program.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 26 bytes

```
=
7^
(((
ROW(
1:6))
 ))&""
```

[Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnAVIpH7vWm35Ropa?e=YweC21)

Below is 17 bytes but Excel removes the line feeds in the array after I hit enter and the output is right justified.

```
=
3^
{2;
4;6;
8;10}
```

Answer (score 1):

## batch <s>63</s> 23 bytes

```bat
:
T^
YP^
E==^
;%~f0
```

Outputs the file content.

**Note:**

- TIO not available, run it from the command line after turning `echo off`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
0
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=0&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Any digit works.

More interestingly,

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 4 bytes

```
2
ʁ↵
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=2%0A%CA%81%E2%86%B5&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
2   # 2
 ʁ  # Range 0-1
  ↵ # 10 ** n (vectorised)
    # (j flag) joined by newlines
```

Using powers of 10.

And finally,

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
3
ɾ×
*⁋,
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=3%0A%C9%BE%C3%97%0A*%E2%81%8B%2C&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
3      # 3
 ɾ     # 1...3
  ×*   # That many asterisks, for each
    ⁋  # Joined by newlines
     , # Outputted.
```

Making an asterisk triangle.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Q
```

[Try it out here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=UQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 1 byte

```
Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P@r/fwA)

In Pyth, `Z` is initialized to 0. Output is implicit so 0 will be printed

---

#### 4 bytes

```
Z
T;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P4orxPr/fwA)

`T` is initialized to 10 and implicitly printed. `;` is a no-op in this context.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 1 byte

```
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P@H/fwA)

The backtick sets the configuration, which in this case is empty. By default, Retina outputs the number of matches of the regex on the input. In this case that regex is the empty string, so the output is `1`

Answer (score 0):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 1 byte

```
o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Mzb@/z///38A)

`o` prints the value of the accumulator, which defaults to 0.

Bit boring, but what can you do about it.

Answer (score 0):

## Deadfish~, 1 byte

```
o
```

Outputs

```
0
```

This is kind of cheating but I can't think of any other way to do it in Deadfish~.